# Which antivirus packages can be configured for on demand scanning only and will not load anything at startup?

Tags: windows, software-rec, anti-virus, anti-spyware

I want a Windows antivirus/antispyware solution that I can use solely for on demand scanning of downloaded files and USB thumb drives.

I don't want it to load anything at startup, save perhaps a right click "Scan This" shell extension.

I definitely don't want it loading any sort of on access resident scanning.

Recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, [ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/). More free & open source suggestions from yours truly.

Straight off the site:

> Please note that ClamWin Free
>   Antivirus does not include an
>   on-access real-time scanner. You need
>   to manually scan a file in order to
>   detect a virus or spyware.

also

> Standalone virus scanner and
>   right-click menu integration to
>   Microsoft Windows Explorer; (context menu)

sounds like what you're looking for!

Comment: Usually I don't mind using open source software but for something like AV that needs continual updates, I'm a bit more sceptical. Do you have any references on how frequently and consistently it gets updated?

Comment: Clamav is very frequently updated. It is primarily used on many mail servers to scan e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com) comes with 7 "providers":

- Internet Mail
- Instant Messaging
- Network Shield
- Outlook/Exchange
- P2P Shield
- Standard Shield
- Web Shield

It's configurable so you can stop the ones you're not interested in. You can also customise the providers that are running to be as light weight as you want.

I'm using it in it's standard configuration with 6 providers running (I haven't got Outlook/Exchange running) and I haven't noticed it slowing my machine down in any way.